# org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: First Element must contain the local name, Envelope , but found html

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, axis

What could be the reason for the following exception from Axis... Http verion used was 1.0.

Read this could be solved if  the following property is set

```
stub._getServiceClient().getOptions().
               setProperty(org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPConstants.CHUNKED,
Boolean.FALSE);
```

But the above property is applicable only for HTTP version 1.1 as per axis docs. 
This property will be ignored by the transport framework if the HTTP version is 1.0.

Any thoughts?

```
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: First Element must contain the local name, Envelope , but found html
 at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430)
 at org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createSOAPMessage(TransportUtils.java:90)
 at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:353)
 at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:416)
 at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:228)
 at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:163)


Caused by: org.apache.axiom.soap.SOAPProcessingException: First Element must contain the local name, Envelope , but found html
 at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.constructNode(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:251)
 at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.createOMElement(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:209)
 at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.createNextOMElement(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:191)
 at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:172)
 at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.getSOAPEnvelope(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:156)
 at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.<init>(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:105)
 at org.apache.axis2.builder.BuilderUtil.getSOAPBuilder(BuilderUtil.java:677)
 at org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createDocumentElement(TransportUtils.java:182)
 at org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createSOAPMessage(TransportUtils.java:112)
 at org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createSOAPMessage(TransportUtils.java:88)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is was actually the server encountering an Internal 500 Error and returning a HTML respose to the client.

Answer (score 7):

Try using a sniffer like tcpmon to see the actual response from the service. My guess is that the client is using a target URL that does not exist on the server and the server is responding with a 404 containing HTML instead of a SOAP envelope.

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat server was serving an HTTP web page to indicate failure in the response to the SOAP API call.